# limit parameter not working in DataFrame reindex_like() function

Tags: python, pandas

I have been practicing pandas library. When I try to use the limit = 1 in reindex_like() function it does not give expected results. 
This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,3),columns=['col1','col2','col3'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2,3),columns=['col1','col2','col3'])

# Padding NAN's
df2.reindex_like(df1)

# Now Fill the NAN's with preceding Values
#print ("Data Frame with Forward Fill limiting to 1:")
df2.reindex_like(df1,method='ffill',limit=1)
```

Expected Output:

[image]

and Output I got:

[image]

What I am doing wrong! Any Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are not printing `df1`, I ran your code and I get the expected result

[image]